# Active or current "state" on css animated button

Tags: css, nav

I cant get active or current "state" on my css-transitions buttons to work.
I tried to use `li a:active` but cant get it to work..

http://planeta.se/bullerWebb/butiken/

[image]

**CSS**

```
    #butikMenu {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 3em 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none; }
    #butikMenu li {
        float: left; }
    #butikMenu{
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 3em 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;*/ }
    #butikMenu li a {
            background:url(images/arrowTest2.png) no-repeat;
            background-position:-300px 0;
            transition: background-position 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px 11px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-size:22px;
            color: #000;
             }
    #butikMenu li a:hover {
            background-position:top right;

            }
    #butikMenu li a:active  {
            background-position:top right;

            }
```

Comment: `:current` is not a CSS pseudo class I think. You probably mean `:active`

Comment: If you want to keep the state after click you may need pure JS or Jquery

Comment: or maybe you meant `a.current`

Comment: you should pass a site-wise variable containing value of which link is active, and on page load, then apply active class to the element - you can add this variable using js or server side language

Comment: Or you can using .current class